# When should I hang my mason bee house?

Tags: pollination

I bought a mason bee house from gardener's supply and I am wondering when should I hang it up?
I am in Berks county, PA.
Here is the link : http://www.gardeners.com/Mason-Bee-House/37-481,default,pd.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

February is a good time for putting these up. February-March is when they're intensely active. Depending on where you are, you may be hitting the end of the season if you wait much longer.

Generally when the fruit trees have dropped all their petals is when they've finished nesting. They will have mudded the larvae in soon after and will be dormant till next year.

One nice thing about Mason Bees is you don't have to worry about flight path, we keep their nests in the green-house eaves and they come out in an uncaring swarm.